# Is a $C^2$ representative unique in $L^2([0,1])$?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I am reading a paper that deals with the solution for the Sturm-Liouville problem's uniqueness of solutions by defining an operator $K$:

$$K:L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$$ 
 $$f \hspace{0.5cm} \longrightarrow u$$

Where u is the solution to the ODE $u'' + \rho u=f$  (With the boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$). It is then shown that the operator $K$ is injective, so that for a given $f \in  L^2([0,1])$ there is a *unique* solution $u \in  L^2([0,1])$.

Also, if $f \in  C([0,1])$, as u verifies $u'' + \rho u=f$ then $u''$ is also continuous so that $u \in  C^2([0,1])$.

So my question is:

> We are dealing with equivalence classes in $L^2([0,1])$, so the
>   uniqueness that comes from the fact that $K$ is injective is for the
>   equivalence class $[u]$. So precisely what I need to know is whether
>   in the set $[u]$ the representative in $C^2([0,1])$ is also unique.

Comment: Yes it is. A continuous representative in $L^1$ is unique. The reason is that any two representatives must agree a.e. and two continuous that agree a.e. are the same everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous representatives are unique whenever they exist. That is just because if you modify a continuous function at one point, to have the result also be a continuous function, you need to make a modification on an interval, which will leave the equivalence class you started in (since intervals have positive measure).

Another way of putting it is that the complement of a measure zero set is always dense, and two continuous functions that agree on a dense set agree everywhere.